# is there a way to use the lua command require to load up the luafilesystem?

Tags: macos, lua, filesystems

i've been trying to install the api but it's not working
kept getting this error

```
stdin:1: module 'Desktop/luafilesystem-master' not found:
no field package.preload['Desktop/luafilesystem-master']
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/Desktop/luafilesystem-master.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/Desktop/luafilesystem-master/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/Desktop/luafilesystem-master.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/Desktop/luafilesystem-master/init.lua'
no file './Desktop/luafilesystem-master.lua'
no file './Desktop/luafilesystem-master/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/Desktop/luafilesystem-master.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
no file './Desktop/luafilesystem-master.so'
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'require'
stdin:1: in main chunk
[C]: in ?
```

also i can't install luarocks for the simple installing i just need it to be a stand alone program so it will temporary , be installed and it can be portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be loading the module as `Desktop/luafilesystem-master`, but in most cases it should be `require "lfs"` and you should have `lfs.so` file available in one of those paths listed in the error message.

If you are compiling from the source, then the result of that compilation will be `lfs.so` file that you need to place in one of those locations.

Comment: i only have ' lfs.def ',is there a way to get ' lfs.so ' or something and what dir do i place the lfs in?

Comment: You need to compile one and can place it in the current folder.

Comment: is there one _precompiled_ or can you teach me how the tutorials are not much help.

Comment: You can grab one for your linux version from https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/tree/master/bin/linux (navigate to x86/x64 and then to `clibs53` if you need one for Lua 5.3).

Comment: i use a school mac book for my work so i can't edit the bin folders and, it seems i need to do that, is there a work around?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but it may be simpler for you to just download ZeroBrane Studio for your platform (or clone the repository), select Lua 5.3 form the list of interpreters and run your script as `require 'lfs'` should work.